# Kibana not showing canvas nor elasticsearch index options

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I upgraded my Kibana and Elasticsearch to 6.8, however, Canvas and the Index Management in the management menu are missing.
I am on OSX. What can I do to show all options?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What did you download exactly? From which URL?

Comment: brew upgrade elasticsearch, brew upgrade kibana and brew upgrade logstash

Comment: I didn't have those options before, but I from what I've read the canvas and other stuff should come by default in kibana since 6.5

Answer (score 1):

Brew is installing a pure OSS version of the stack instead of the one which which contains features available with an elastic license.
Some of those features are free with the default basic license.

If you want to have access to those, you need to download the default distribution from [elastic.co website](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/) and just launch it.